# How do I send a message to the view that a duplicate entry exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some code that is checking for possible duplicate entries. What I'm struggling with is where and what to put to let the user know - probably a modal of some sort, displaying the message that a duplicate user already exists.

**Model**

```cs
public void SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
        {
            USERACCOUNT objUserAccount = new USERACCOUNT
            {

                HPID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans),
                DOMAIN = "Aeth",
                NTUSERID = objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id,
                ROLEID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.UserRole),
                FIRSTNAME = objSearchRolesViewModel.FirstName,
                LASTNAME = objSearchRolesViewModel.LastName,
                EMAIL = objSearchRolesViewModel.Email,
                ACTIVE = true/*Convert.ToBoolean(objSearchRolesViewModel.ActiveStatus)*/,
                DEFAULTPLANID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan),
                CREATEID = userID.Substring(5).ToUpper(),
                CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now,
                UPDATEID = userID.Substring(5).ToUpper(),
                UPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
            };

            if (CheckforDuplicate(objUserAccount.NTUSERID, objUserAccount.HPID).Count == 0)
            {
                _context.USERACCOUNTs.Add(objUserAccount);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                WHAT GOES HERE
            }


        }
```

**Controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(SearchRolesViewModel searchRolesViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                SearchRolesModel objUser = new SearchRolesModel();

                if (searchRolesViewModel.User_Id != string.Empty && searchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans != string.Empty && searchRolesViewModel.UserRole != string.Empty && searchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan != string.Empty)
                {
                    objUser.SaveUser(searchRolesViewModel, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString());
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "User added successfully";
                }
                return UserDetails();
            }
            else
            {
                OR SHOULD IT GO HERE
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw ;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a return value.

```
public bool SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
{
    /* Snip */

    bool duplicate = CheckforDuplicate(objUserAccount.NTUSERID, objUserAccount.HPID).Count == 0;

    if (duplicate) return false;

    _context.USERACCOUNTs.Add(objUserAccount);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

Then check the return value in your controller:

```
var ok = objUser.SaveUser(searchRolesViewModel, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString());
if (ok)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    ViewBag.Message = "User added successfully";
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Message = "User not added.";
}
```

Comment: These changes added the duplicate user the DB. I'm wondering if there's a bool value that should be switched?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a repository base with a few generic queries. E.g Add, GetAll, Find, Exists, Count and others. For more details https://medium.com/falafel-software/implement-step-by-step-generic-repository-pattern-in-c-3422b6da43fd

https://medium.com/@marekzyla95/generic-repository-pattern-implemented-in-net-core-with-ef-core-c7e088c9c58

for example, a possible implementation for a generic `Exists` method:

```
public bool Exists(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> func)
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>()
                   .Where(func)
                   .Any();
}
```

where TEntity will to be the model `USERACCOUNT`

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(SearchRolesViewModel searchRolesViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchRolesModel objUser = new SearchRolesModel();

            if (searchRolesViewModel.User_Id != string.Empty && searchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans != string.Empty && searchRolesViewModel.UserRole != string.Empty && searchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan != string.Empty)
            {
                //here we call the Exists method from an user repository to check for duplicate entries 
                var isDuplicated = _userRepository.Exists(user => user.NTUSERID == objUser.NTUSERID && user.HPID == objUser.HPID);

               if(isDuplicated) 
               {
                   ViewBag.Message = "User exists already!";
                   Return Foo(); // return for the more appropriate page
               }
               else
               {
                   objUser.SaveUser(searchRolesViewModel, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString());
                   ModelState.Clear();
                   ViewBag.Message = "User added successfully";
                   return UserDetails();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw ;
        }

    }
```